# Reading annotations with Symfony4

Tags: php, annotations, symfony4

I'm trying to read annotations with Symfony4 but looks like something is not working!

The class I'm trying to read from:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OAuthClientRepository")
 */
class OAuthClient {
{

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

}
```

The code I'm using to read the annotations:

```
<?php

namespace App\Test;

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\SimpleAnnotationReader as DocReader;

/**
 * Helper AnnotationReader
 */
class AnnotationReader
{

    /**
     * @param $class
     * @return null|\StdClass
     */
    public static function getClass($class)
    {
        $reader = new DocReader;
        $reflector = new \ReflectionClass($class);
        return $reader->getClassAnnotations($reflector);
    }

    /**
     * @param $class
     * @param $property
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getProperty($class, $property)
    {
        $reader = new DocReader;
        $reflector = new \ReflectionProperty($class, $property);
        return $reader->getPropertyAnnotations($reflector);
    }

    /**
     * @param $class
     * @param $method
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getMethod($class, $method)
    {
        $reader = new DocReader;
        $reflector = new \ReflectionMethod($class, $method);
        return $reader->getMethodAnnotations($reflector);
    }

}
```

I get empty arrays when I call:

```
App\Test\AnnotationReader::getClass(App\Entity\OAuthClient::class);
App\Test\AnnotationReader::getProperty(App\Entity\OAuthClient::class, 'name');
```

What am I doing wrong?
What is the best way to read annotation?

I'm looking to read the validations used on a class property.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

change

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\SimpleAnnotationReader as DocReader;
```

to

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader as DocReader;
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to call the `addNamespace()` method on the `SimpleAnnotationReader` instance.

For instance, for ORM annotations:

```
$reader->addNamespace('Doctrine\ORM\Mapping');
```

And for validation annotations:

```
$reader->addNamespace('Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints');
```

See:

- `SimpleAnnotationReader` API: https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/annotations/latest/Doctrine/Annotations/SimpleAnnotationReader.html
- `SimpleAnnotationReader` examples: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/462173ad71ae63cd9877e1e642f7968ed1f9971b/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php#L140-L141